# Log IOError only in console, don't send mails

Tags: django

In my Django Project, I get informed about IOErrors that happen sometimes when users upload data to the website. I wan't to turn off the email notification when IOErrors happen.

I found out how to write a filter, so I can [get rid of the IOError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375950/getting-rid-of-django-ioerrors). But how can I change this to log the error, but only to console, not per mail.

**settings.py**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        },
        'suppress_unreadable_post': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': SuppressUnreadablePost,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'include_html': True,
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'myapp': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'ratelimitbackend': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

And my filter:

```
import sys, traceback

class SuppressUnreadablePost(object):
    def filter(self, record):
        _, exception, tb = sys.exc_info()
        if isinstance(exception, IOError):
            for _, _, function, _ in traceback.extract_tb(tb):
                if function == '_get_raw_post_data':
                    return False
        return True
```

Ideas :)? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting rid of Django IOErrors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375950/getting-rid-of-django-ioerrors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your filter is correct, you only need to edit your mail_admins handler to add the filter:

```
   'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false', 'suppress_unreadable_post'],
        'include_html': True,
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
```

Like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.CallbackFilter